# Regex match numbers from 1-10, including decimals

Tags: regex

Im matching numbers like these:

```
0
1
1.5
2
2.1
3
3.5
..
up to
10
```

What would be a good regex to match these numbers?

EDIT: Acceptable numbers should be: one integer between 0 and 10, followed by 0 or 1 decimal, in the form of an integer between 1 and 9.

I dont have the numbers ready to go, i need to match them inside complicated html.

Example 1:

```
<div style="whatever">gotta match this number 3.5</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<what>11 dont match it
```

Example 3:

```
<what>9<weirdtag>match me</div>
```

Comment: Parse it as a number and then check the range.

Comment: is 10.0 acceptable? is 10.1 acceptable? is 0.0 acceptable? is 0 acceptable? is 000.1 acceptable? Or are the only acceptable values integers and decimals with .5 as the decimal part? Please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go down the regex route then I believe this horrible regex matches your requirements:

```
(?<![\d\.-])\d(\.\d)?(?!(\.\d)|\d)|(?<![\d\.-])10(?!(\.\d)|\d])
```

**How it works:**

If you remove the boundary conditions then the regex looks much simpler:

```
\d(\.\d)? | 10
```

This matches **EITHER** *"a digit, optionally followed by a period AND a digit"*  **OR**  *"the number 10"* (with no decimal places) as per your requirements.

The other parts of the regex add [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) behaviour to ensure that the regex doesn't match negative numbers, or digits followed by a period and more digits. This is to ensure that something like this:

```
10.5
```

doesn't yield two different matches: "10" *and then* "5".

**Note**

This will **NOT** match `.5  .7  .9` (but *will* match `0.5  0.7  0.9`)

Also, it will **NOT** match `10.0` (but *will* match `10`)

[**View Online Example HERE**](https://regex101.com/r/sG1mA3/2)

Answer (score 1):

You could match this more easily without a RegEx, just using conditionals, like this:

```js
var string = 'sljfkd;4lskf8iel5.3jslkd;a';

var numbers = string.match(/\d\.*\d*/gm);

var matches = [];

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

  if (numbers[i] >= 1 && numbers[i] <= 10) {

    matches[matches.length] = numbers[i];

  }

}

alert(matches);
```

Please don't use a RegEx to do this - it will get very messy.

Comment: but i dont have the numbers available and ready, i need to match them inside html code.

Comment: Ahhh. I see.  Try using a combination of the two.  I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
(?<!\d)(\d(?:\.[1-9])?|10)(?!\d)
```

Where:

```
(?<!\d)     : negative look behind assuming there're no digits before
(           : begin capture group 1
  \d        : a digit
  (?:       : begin non capture group
    \.      : a dot
    [1-9]   : a digit between 1 and 9
  )?        : end group, optional
  |         : OR
  10        : number 10
)           : end group 1
(?!\d)      : negative lookahead, no digits after
```

Comment: Note: This will match the "8" in "8.91" (which may or may not be acceptable to the original poster)... It will also match ".6" as "6" (again this *might* be acceptable?)... It will also match "-9" as "9"

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do (if you use comma like point notation `,` and you want only to have one accurrence) is:

`^(\d|(\d\,\d)|10){1}$`

You cat test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/gSnRVs/2).